# Hocon: Read an array of objects from a configuration file

Tags: json, scala, configuration, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have created an Play application (2.1) which uses the configuration in `conf/application.conf` in the [Hocon format](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).

I want to add an array of projects in the configuration. The file `conf/application.conf` looks like this:

```
...
projects = [
  {name: "SO", url: "http://stackoverflow.com/"},
  {name: "google", url: "http://google.com"}
]
```

I try to read this configuration in my Scala project:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
case class Project(name: String, url: String)

val projectList: List[Project] =
  Play.maybeApplication.map{x =>
    val simpleConfig = x.configration.getObjectList("projects").map{y =>
      y.toList.map{z =>
        Project(z.get("name").toString, z.get("url").toString) // ?!? doesn't work

      ... 
   }}}}}}}}  // *arg*
```

This approach seems to be very complicated, I am lost in a lot of `Options`, and my Eclipse IDE cannot give me any hints about the classes.

Has anybody an example how you can read an array of objects from a Hocon configuration file?
Or should I use for this a JSON-file with an JSON-parser instead of Hocon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following works for me in Play 2.1.2 (I don't have a `.maybeApplication` on my `play.Play` object though, and I'm not sure why you do):

```
import play.Play
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
case class Project(name: String, url: String)

val projectList: List[Project] = {
  val projs = Play.application.configuration.getConfigList("projects") map { p => 
    Project(p.getString("name"), p.getString("url")) }
  projs.toList
}

println(projectList)
```

Giving output:

```
List(Project(SO,http://stackoverflow.com/), Project(google,http://google.com))
```

There's not a whole lot different, although I don't get lost in a whole lot of `Option` instances either (again, different from the API you seem to have).

More importantly, `getConfigList` seems to be a closer match for what you want to do, since it returns `List[play.Configuration]`, which enables you to specify types on retrieval instead of resorting to casts or `.toString()` calls.

Comment: Thanks, looks a lot easier. I will check this answer in a few weeks (...holidays...) with Play 2.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish with this part `y.toList.map{z =>`?  If you want a collection of `Project` as the result, why not just do:

```
val simpleConfig = x.configration.getObjectList("projects").map{y =>
   Project(y.get("name").toString, y.get("url").toString)
}
```

In this case, the `map` operation should be taking instances of `ConfigObject` which is what `y` is.  That seems to be all you need to get your `Project` instances, so I'm not sure why you are `toList`ing that `ConfigObject` (which is a `Map`) into a List of `Tuple2` and then further mapping that again.

Comment: `getObjectList` returns a `Option[java.util.List[_ <: ConfigObject]]`, so `y` is a `java.util.List[_ <: ConfigObject]`. Another thing: `y.get("name").toString` is f.ex. `ConfigString("google")`, I don't know how to get the raw value from it. It seems so complicated to read an object array, there must be an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

If a normal HOCON configuration then similar to strangefeatures answer this will work

```
import javax.inject._
import play.api.Configuration

trait Barfoo {
  def configuration: Configuration     
  def projects = for {
    projectsFound <- configuration.getConfigList("projects").toList
    projectConfig <- projectsFound
    name <- projectConfig.getString("name").toList
    url  <- projectConfig.getString("url").toList
  } yield Project(name,url)
}

class Foobar @Inject() (val configuration: Configuration) extends Barfoo
```

(Using Play 2.4+ Injection)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the contents of the array are Json and you have a case class, you could try to use the [Json Play API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJson) and work with the objects in that way. The [Inception](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonInception) part should make it trivial.

Comment: Yes, parsing a JSON file seems to be a lot easier than parsing Hocon. This would be a solution, but then I loose the advantages that offers Hocon over Json. A Hocon-Parser-API like the Json Play Api would be cool.